# Honeycomb launcher title truncated

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am working on my first honeycomb application. The name of the app is fairly long and the launcher title is getting truncated/faded. I'm having trouble finding out whether it's possible to break this into multiple lines so that the entire title is visible. Anyone know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot control how the application label is displayed by the Launcher, that is up the Launcher.

So you'll either have to shorten the name you use as the label for the Launcher, or accept the fading/truncating of your label.

You could try adding a `\n` at the point where you want a line-break in your String, but I doubt this would have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a way to prevent truncation of the action bar title. The solution is to make the action bar title short.